# How to understand the source code of warpAffine in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am studying the source code of `cv::warpAffine()` in opencv and I got 2 questions.

Here is the first question. Just like the following codes, after the transformation matrix is computed by calling the function `cv::getAffineTransform()` then we call `cv::warpAffine()` to warp the image.

```
cv::Point2f src[3], dst[3];
src[0] = cv::Point2f(35.148750, 255.26263);
src[1] = cv::Point2f(293.08679, 215.27223);
src[2] = cv::Point2f(153.83780, 168.80141);

dst[0] = cv::Point2f(35.000000, 275.00000);
dst[1] = cv::Point2f(293.00000, 215.00000);
dst[2] = cv::Point2f(116.00000, 126.00000);

cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/Users/CJZ/Desktop/TestSample/eye_test.jpg");
cv::Mat reslt = cv::Mat(image.rows * 1.3, image.cols * 1.3, image.type(), cv::Scalar::all(255));

cv::Mat warpMat = cv::getAffineTransform(src, dst);
cv::warpAffine(image, reslt, warpMat, reslt.size());
```

When I see the source code of `cv::warpAffine()`, I found the transformation matrix is recomputed again.

```
if( !(flags & WARP_INVERSE_MAP) )
{
    double D = M[0]*M[4] - M[1]*M[3];
    D = D != 0 ? 1./D : 0;
    double A11 = M[4]*D, A22=M[0]*D;
    M[0] = A11; M[1] *= -D;
    M[3] *= -D; M[4] = A22;
    double b1 = -M[0]*M[2] - M[1]*M[5];
    double b2 = -M[3]*M[2] - M[4]*M[5];
    M[2] = b1; M[5] = b2;
}
```

What is the meaning of this computation ?

Here is the second question. I found some enum variables in source code and they confuse me. It seems that we can use them to optimize the speed but why ? I hope someone can give me details about the optimization.

```
enum
{
    INTER_BITS=5, INTER_BITS2=INTER_BITS*2,
    INTER_TAB_SIZE=(1<<INTER_BITS),
    INTER_TAB_SIZE2=INTER_TAB_SIZE*INTER_TAB_SIZE
};
```

And the last thing. I found the architecture of the `cv::warpAffine` is large and difficult for me. Are there some articles about it ?

Comment: These are linear algebra (matrix inverse) and fixed point (finite precision) arithmetics. The need to invert the matrix is that for the purpose of generating an output image, it is much more useful to have a function that takes the output coordinates, and return back the input coordinates. Posting as comment since I'm not hundred percent sure, and I won't have time to dig deeper.

Comment: yes, inverse is used to compute exactly one pixel value for each pixel of the destination image.

Comment: @rwong,@Micka,yes, I think you are right, thankyou~

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your last question: have a look on George Wolberg's book on Digital Image Warping it covers affine (2D) warping.